# Distinct Count Different Columns and Display Result into Multiple Columns in access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am pretty new to SQL and Ms Access Database.
Had searched through some posts online but still confused on `DISTINCT COUNT` function.

May I know if the below can be done in a simple way without creating multiple queries or VBA code (due to performance issue)? Or can use sub-query and if yes how can it be done please?
Truly appreciate your advices please.

Many Thanks and Cheers
Pele

**Table: Material**

[image]

**Result as below:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

MS Access doesn't support `COUNT(DISTINCT)`, so this is tricky.  One method uses subqueries.  I think this will work:

```
select c.col0,
       (select count(*)
        from (select distinct m2.col1
              from material as m2
              where m2.col0 = c.col0
             ) as m2
       ) as dcol1,
       (select count(*)
        from (select distinct m2.col2
              from material as m2
              where m2.col0 = c.col0
             ) as m2
       ) as dcol2,
       (select count(*)
        from (select distinct m2.col3
              from material as m2
              where m2.col0 = c.col0
             ) as m2
       ) as dcol3
from (select distinct col0 from material) as c;
```

I'm not 100% sure if MS Access supports the correlation clause two levels deep.  If not, you can write this as:

```
select c.col0,
       (select count(*)
        from (select distinct m2.col0, m2.col1
              from material as m2
             ) as m2
        where m2.col0 = c.col0
       ) as dcol1,
```

But the first better would have better performance.

EDIT:

For these queries, you want an index on `(col0, col1)`.

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff, thanks for your advices! And yes performance is my main concern too as I may need to run more than 50K lines of records in Ms Access.  The first one seems working fine but may I know how can I avoid to input the value of Col0 each time when I execute the query please?  The second one seems shorter codes but I am unable to execute it. Can I define AS DCol1, DCol2, DCol3 after SELECT DISTINCT m2.Col0, m2.Col1, M2.Col3?  Please find attached TestDB.accdb  https://www.dropbox.com/s/u28lvc3ew7nt0vv/TestDB.accdb?dl=0

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff, do you have any clue on this please?

Answer (score 0):

This suggests me simple `GROUP BY` with `COUNT(DISTINCT)` :

```
SELECT Col0, COUNT(DISTINCT Col1) AS DCol1, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT Col2) AS DCol2, COUNT(DISTINCT Col3) AS DCol3
FROM table t
GROUP BY Col0;
```

`DISTINCT COUNT` is not a `FUNCTION`, there is two things one is `FUNCTION` which is `COUNT()` & other is `DISTINCT` which can be used for uniqueness.

You can also use it with `SELECT` statement to make entire row to unique.

**EDIT** : If the `DISTINCT` inside `COUNT()` function doesn't work, then you use correlation approach :

```
select distinct c.col0,
       (select count(*)
        from (select distinct m1.col1
              from material as m1
              where m1.col0 = m.col0
             ) as m1
       ) as dcol1,
       (select count(*)
        from (select distinct m2.col2
              from material as m2
              where m2.col0 = m.col0
             ) as m2
       ) as dcol2,
       (select count(*)
        from (select distinct m3.col3
              from material as m3
              where m3.col0 = m.col0
             ) as m3
       ) as dcol3
from material as m;
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Yogesh Sharman!! yes you are right that I have tried COUNT(DISTINCT) in Ms Access but unfortunately it didn't work. So I modified a bit of your codes as attached, also a good advices shared from Gordon Linoff in this thread.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/u28lvc3ew7nt0vv/TestDB.accdb?dl=0  Just had a question how can I avoid to input value of Col0 each time I execute the query.